# Come tradurre: attendable?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, translation

**To attend** in italiano si traduce come **partecipare** giusto?

Ma come posso tradurre **attendable**?

Il contesto è un sito web di eventi - dove il termine è dato come parola singola e non all'interno di una frase.

Letteralmente potrebbe essere **partecipabile**. Ma suona male no?
Come posso dirlo in italiano?

Grazie!

Comment: Complimenti per l'impegno che ci metti, considerando tutti i siti non tradotti, mal tradotti, tradotti con Google etc. che si vedono in giro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certo, “partecipabile” non può andare bene anche perché – in questo senso, riferito a eventi – “partecipare” non è transitivo: non è che tu *“partecipi un evento”. Invece *to attend* in questa accezione è transitivo (*I attended a conference*).

È pensabile qualcosa che non traduce veramente il senso ma forse va bene per il contesto come “prenotabile” o simili?

Answer (score 0):

**To attend** può tradurre con partecipare, ma una alternativa più calzante in questo contesto potrebbe essere ***frequentare***, quindi una traduzione potrebbe essere "evento **frequentabile**"

Infatti **to attend** si può usare per dire "Io frequento la scuola" (I attend school)

Comment: Ma qui si parla di eventi (spettacoli, convegni o simili, suppongo), non di scuola. Se io vedessi un sito in cui si parla di “frequentare un concerto”, per esempio, mi chiederei con quali piedi l'hanno fatto.

Comment: Diciamo che frequentare di solito indica una azione abituale. Si potrebbe dire "Io ogni anno frequento corsi/convegni/eventi di aggiornamento". Con la parola concerto in effetti lo trovo un pò forzato.